# Array.map resulting in poor performance when rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that is causing poor performance issues for me. It takes data and creates a text list of moves for a game. Whenever I click one of the navigation buttons to go backwards or forwards through this game, if there are a large number of moves, the whole thing slows down. So, I am presuming I have some kind of bottleneck in my code affecting its speed.

The code I am using is below. I'm using Material UI components to format the move list.

Any ideas on why this might be slow, or ways to speed it up?

Edit: After commenting out the following ListItemText, speed was much better. Given that, does it give any clues to a solution?

```
<ListItemText
  style={{ lineHeight: 0, margin: 0 }}
  classes={{ primary: props.classes.listItemText }}
  // dense={true}
  primary={props.chess.history()[index]}
/>;
```

```
export default function MoveList(
  props
) {
  return (
    <Grid container direction="row">
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folders">
          {props.chess.history().map((each, index) => {
            if (index % 2 === 0) {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, margin: 0 }}
                  button
                  selected={props.selectedIndex === index + 1}
                  onClick={event => {
                                      }}
                >
                  <ListItemText
                    style={{ lineHeight: 0, margin: 0 }}
                    classes={{ primary: props.classes.listItemText }}
                    primary={props.chess.history()[index]}
                  />
                </ListItem>
              );
            } else return null;
          })}
        </List>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <List
          component="nav"
        >
          {props.chess.history().map((each, index) => {
            if (index % 2 !== 0) {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, margin: 0 }}
                  button
                  selected={props.selectedIndex === index + 1}
                  onClick={event => {

                  }}
                >
                  <ListItemText
                    style={{ lineHeight: 0, margin: 0 }}
                    classes={{ primary: props.classes.listItemText }}
                    primary={props.chess.history()[index]}
                  />
                </ListItem>
              );
            } else return null;
          })}
        </List>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: In general it is a good idea to perform the following experiment: (temporarily) remove some resources from your example one-by-one, always benchmarking the time. Once large time difference is detected between a try and the previous try, you have probably just removed the bottleneck. That would help you in narrowing down your problem-space and maybe it will answer the question by itself. If not, then some further experimenting on the bottleneck should set you towards the right direction.

Comment: Add "key" props to your ListItem components. Look at the browser console, it's probably complaining about missing key

Comment: I've added the key to the ListItem components using `key={each.concat('black').concat(index.toString())}` but I saw no performance improvement.

Comment: I've edited my original post to show that when I comment out ListItemText, performance is much better. But I obviously need that in there! Does it give any clue to a solution?

Comment: kinda? but at that point it may benefit to further dig into ListItemText component and repeat the process.

Comment: Ok, I have narrowed it down to the line `primary={props.chess.history()[index]}`
If I remove that line for each of the 3 segments in my code, performance is normal. But that line is what displays the text. There are 60 rows of data in my test.

Comment: I just tried changing the code to `primary="data"` and performance seems normal. So, it is something about this lookup that is causing the problem: `props.chess.history()[index]`

Comment: Solved it thanks to your guys help. I will answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance bottleneck was found to be looking up `chess.history()[index]`. So, I did this before the return statement:

`let moveHistory = props.chess.history();`

And then I just used this instead:

```
primary={moveHistory[index]}
```